# batch file - read ini file ignoring comments

Tags: windows, batch-file

Given this sample.ini file:

```
[this is a comment1]
Parameter1=sun

[this is a comment2]
Parameter2=is

[this is a comment3]
Parameter3=shining
```

I wrote this batch to process that process the sample.ini and sets each entry as an Environment variable

How can i filter out the ini comments from the for loop?
because it throws errors:

```
C:\temp>set [this is a comment1]
Environment variable [this is a comment1] not defined
```

Here is the batch file
nothing but a for loop that iterates over the INI and assign to %%G then sets it as Environment variable

```
REM @ECHO OFF

for /f "delims=" %%G in (sample.ini) do set %%G

PAUSE
```

Comment: An INI file does not enclose **comments** within brackets. Comments are prepended with semicolons, whereas Sections are enclosed within brackets. So my assumption is that you want EITHER all lines containing keys, (with or without values), OR all uncommented lines containing keys, (with or without values). And all regardless of whether matching key names are found within different Sections. One possibility: ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RV "^[;\[]" sample.ini```

Comment: You may even find that something as simple as this is sufficient, ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "=" 0<sample.ini```. In a `for` loop that would be ```@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "=" 0^<sample.ini 2^>NUL') Do @Set "%%G"```

Comment: That was my issue! semicolon fixed this!!! thank you so much

Comment: @compo can you post this as an answer, ill accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As [compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) pointed out: in an .ini file comments are prepended by `;`.

Option 1: So if you just want to filter out the lines that starts with a `[` and `;` you can use `findstr`:

```bash
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('type sample.ini ^| findstr /v "^[;\[]"') do set %%G
```

As an Explanation it search for lines which do not, (`/v`), match, the characters, `;`, and `[`, (`[` is a regex metacharacter, and requires escaping with a backward slash, `\`).

Option 2: you can also search directly for an `=` by:

```bash
... ('find "=" 0^<sample.ini 2^>NUL') do set %%G
```